# Implementing MVP in Android app

Tags: android, mvp

Every Android Developer faces with problem, that Activities or Fragments are to complicated, because most apps use only View-Model design. As do I, so I started looking for better solution.

What caught my attention is MVP, which is old design, but is regenerated ever and again.

I think [this article](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/android-application-architecture-8b6e34acda65#.am2m2y4wd) and their [example](https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate) is very helpful, but I found one possible problem.

I assume that we can create app in this way:

Fragments and Activities are part of *View*. They are connected with *Presenter* which calls DataManager for loading content. DataManager as a part of *Model* has reference to every data helper. But here DataManager starts to be God in our application, because it has every method for every Presenter.

I also found second possible problem. 
Presenter can hold data for example in list, so every time when we change orientation of the screen we don't have to call DataManager for new content. But have no idea how to achieve that presenter is not related to Activity life cycle except having static field in our Activity.

To sum up:

**1.** Is it better to somehow create multiple DataManagers and when one DataManager starts to be overloaded? What is the best way to implement multiple DataManagers?

**2.** How to implement relation between *Presenter* and *View*, where *Presenter* is not related to Activity life cycle?

I could misunderstood some ideas, so every help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This shows exactly how MVP should look imho

[image: This shows exactly how MVP should look imho]

**EDIT 2**

Because post was assigned as too broad, I would like to ask only

**1.** Is it good pattern to make DataManager as God class or should I implement multiple DataManagers? If so, what is the best way?

Comment: Though "there isn't the best way, just a better way". I really don't think DataManager can be an elegant implementation. After getting rid of the God Activity, now we have another God in our model layer. It seems no problem in small projects, but with a common level of business requirements, the DataManager would be growing so fast til we are too tired to do that any longer.